# Can ZendAMF have private members?

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework

I've worked with AMFPHP for a while, but with Adobe supporting ZendAMF, I was wondering if I should migrate.

One of the major disadvantages for AMFPHP is that class mappings need to be public, so not only does that mean public members on the PHP side, but also on the Flex side. I was wondering if it is the same case for ZendAMF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know they must be public - otherwise the server wrapper cannot call the methods.